# Windows installer error 0xc8000222

Tags: .net, frameworks

I cann't install .NET Framework, and receive error 0xc8000222
I've search for solved-the-same-error, but no work for my PC. And I cann't update my windows, too.
Here is my log when installing .NET

`OS Version = 6.1.7600, SP = 0.0, Platform 2
OS Description = Windows 7 - x64 Ultimate Edition 
MSI = 5.0.7600.16385
Windows version = amd64_windowsfoundation_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_5f2ecc1aaa4ac3b2.manifest
Windows servicing = 6.1.7600.16385
CommandLine = C:\5403520ff8bdbac4f26d4bf476\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /redist
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Setup
Package Version = 4.5.50938
User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled
Number of applicable items: 11
Exe (C:\5403520ff8bdbac4f26d4bf476\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
Exe (C:\5403520ff8bdbac4f26d4bf476\Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.msu) failed with 0xc8000222 - (null).
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0xC8000222) (Elapsed time: 0 00:03:11).`

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you tried? The first result on google shows me [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-failing-0xc8000222/6d55c63a-316c-4e9d-97b2-538bc783cdad), what were your results?

Comment: Solved! Thanks for view

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so this can be accepted.

Answer (score 13):

You can solve this by following the instructions [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-failing-0xc8000222/6d55c63a-316c-4e9d-97b2-538bc783cdad).

- Click Start
- Type: `cmd`
- Right click on `cmd` in start menu and select '*Run as Administrator*'
- Type: `net stop wuauserv`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type: `ren c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution softwaredistribution.old`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type: `net start wuauserv`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type: exit
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks  a lot, I searched a lot for fixing this problem.